# Use tags for tableView inside UIViewController to update Labels

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, tags, ios9.1

I added a table view to my UIViewController. then i added a label to my custom cell inside the table view. i tried to update labels inside the tableview by using tags. seems it does not working.

this is my code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LineItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let object = lineItemsObject[indexPath.row]
    //cell.textLabel?.text = object["quantity"]

    print(object["description"]!)

    if let descriptionLabel = cell.viewWithTag(500) as? UILabel {
        descriptionLabel.text = object["description"]
    }
    else
    {
        print("fail")
    }

    return cell
}
```

When i call the function always it does not read the tag and prints "fail". i have assigned correct tag value to my label also.

here i have attached a image of my label details in attribute inspector
[image]

Please help me the fix the issue.

Comment: Your Code looks fine. I checked it with a test Project and it works fine.
Try this :

Delete the cell that comes with the table view. Drag and drop a new cell from the Object Browser, now add a label, set its tag and then the Cell identifier and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cell is not knowing about your label inside (the one with 500 tag). You are not providing a custom cell, because of this line:

```
let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LineItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

This is a predefined cell. As of documentation you can have predefined cells or custom ones (obtained by subclassing UITableViewCell):

"When creating cells, you can customize them yourself or use one of several predefined styles. The predefined cell styles are the simplest option. With the predefined styles, the cell provides label and image subviews whose positions and styling are fixed. ...  To set the text and images of the cell, use the textLabel, detailTextLabel, and imageView properties."

1. **If you want to go predefined:** 
   If you want to just put the text onto cell use (I see this one is commented on first place).

   cell.textLabel?.text = object["quantity"]
2. **Go custom**

Extend UITableViewCell on a separate swift file. Do your bindings here and work with your storyboard in parallel. Assign the custom class to your cell. Also, change dequeue:

```
let cell: MyCustomTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LineItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
```

Comment: I modified the line you mentioned and remove codeline for register UITableViewCell class for the table view. now it is working fine

Answer (score 2):

As @TheAppMentor said code looks fine. Make sure you entered correct cell identifier. Then make sure you connected your view controller to correct class (it's my common mistake). Also make sure that something else in this cell hasn't the same tag. You can also print all subviews to check what's inside.

Comment: I verified all of things you mentioned. but does not work. as well as i printed subviews. there are three UITableViewCellContentViews.

Comment: Here i have registered class UITableViewCell for the table. i removed it and now it is working fine